# I meet this error when i use keystone

Tags: openstack

I'm new for openstack. I used this command:

```
keystone user-list
```

but it showed:

> Authorization Failed: The resource could not be found. (HTTP 404)
>   (Request-ID: req-0022eaa4-c2f9-480b-b069-bc93eeed8d06)

and then i used this:

```
openstack  user-list
```

and it worked.

So, I wonder if `"keystone user-list"` was removed?
thanks for answer

Comment: Have you installed `virtualenv`?

Comment: no.i find answer in internet ,it do be removed,i was replaced by "openstack.. ..."